# Retrofitting an Incremental ID column with UPDATE

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a MySQL table with an ID column, intended to be imported from external data, but for this one case there were no IDs provided. Therefore, I have a column of pure zeros. I need to update this column to have unique values in each row, and these numbers have no significance. I can think of several ways to do it, but I'm wondering what the correct way would be. My first idea was something like `UPDATE table SET id = (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM table)` - but I like elegant solutions when available.

*Edit:* It turns out running this query triggers `1093: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause` - I guess that means I really need a more elegant solution, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, since nothing was working:

```
update table set accountnumber = floor(rand() * 999999999)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t
SET    t.id = q.id
FROM   TABLE t
       INNER JOIN
              ( SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS id
              FROM    TABLE
              )
              q
       ON     1 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error though, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM   TABLE t
       INNER JOIN
              ( SELECT MAX(accountnumber)+1 A' at line 3`

Comment: try to put table names/fields in ` ( select * from `table)  If problem remains please provide dump

Comment: `UPDATE t
SET    t.accountnumber = q.id
FROM   rptc t
       INNER JOIN
              ( SELECT MAX(accountnumber)+1 AS id
              FROM    rptc
              )
              q
       ON     1 = 1;` This is what I'm working with. Still getting that same error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad example above for mssql. Here is for MySQL: `UPDATE tmp AS t
       INNER JOIN
              ( SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS id
              FROM    tmp
              )
              q
       ON     1          = 1
       SET    t.build_id = q.id`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you generate a View of the table  where you add an expression column wich can generate a unique identifier much like you are proposing and then import the view?